# Induce controller UI change from within directive with shared variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

So i have a controller which hides/shows part of its template based on value, let's say its something like this:
`<div ng-show="isSelected"></div>`

```
...
$scope.isSelected = true;
...
```

Pretty standard stuff, huh ?

Now, i have a directive to which im passing this flag:
`<my-directive select="isSelected"></mydirective>`

And in this directive i have it bound like this:

```
...
// Angular 1.4 syntax here mind you
bindToController: {
    select: '=',
}
...
```

So in the controller of my directive i change this flag at some point, and i'd like that to be propagated all the way to the parent controller UI which should change.
I checked manually in DevTools that value on the controller is changed by the directive - so thats good.
But i have no idea how to cause UI refresh. It feels like something should be in `$watch()` or `$apply()`, but i have no idea if and where should i put something like that.

Alternative solution i used to date was to pass function from controller to my directive which changes this value, after being called - that worked, but it feels like a bad design since it results in more or less same function had to be added each time i want to use directive :/
Any tips will be of course greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following bit of code shows a sample of what you are trying to achieve

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrlr">
        <div ng-show="isSelected">If I disappear, the directive is responsible.</div>
        <my-directive select="isSelected"></my-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrlr', function ($scope) {
        $scope.isSelected = true;
    })
    .directive('myDirective', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            controller: function () {
                var ctrl = this;
                // the $timeout is just to put the delay in
                $timeout(function () {
                    ctrl.select = false;
                }, 2000)
            },
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {
                select: '=',
            }
        }
    }])
```

The value of the myCtrlr scope variable `select` is modified from within the directive (here its done after a delay, but it could be triggered from something like a UI action)

Comment: i realized what i did wrong... i was passing this variable in an object (i presented simplified case obviously), and when i changed `$scope.select` to $scope.flags = {select: true}` i forgot to change all my ng-shows and stuff to `flags.select`. Sorry to waste your time for this answer, but here, have some points for your trouble ;)

Comment: Cheers! And Thanks! :-)